# How to make a submenu appear properly below parent <li>?

Tags: html, css, navbar, navigationbar

Hi I am having trouble getting my submenus to line up nicely below my menu items. I've tried researching it but almost everything gives ideas for floating menus, instead of a `display:table` one like I've done.

Here's a snippet: http://codepen.io/ruchiccio/pen/ZGGQvR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can line the submenu up to the left side of the parent menu items by removing padding on the nested `ul` elements.

```
#navigation1 nav ul li ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVVxJZ